Difference between weight matrix and loading matrix in PCA
Currently I am working with PCA techniques (specifically sparse PCA techniques) but my question revolves around obtaining the weight matrix in PCA.
This reference provides the following representation for PCA:
$X = X W P' + E$
Where $X$ is the data matrix containing the scores for $I$ observations and $J$ variables. Assume we choose to have $Q$ components, then $W$ is a $J \times Q$ weight matrix, $P$ is a $J \times Q$ loading matrix, and $E$ is a $I \times J$ residual matrix. He further mentions that it is often respresented with $T = XW$ (so $X = TP' +E$).
My confusion arises when I want to inspect the matrices. PCA in scikit-learn for example provides only the loading matrix but for my work I require the weight matrix as well. Other implementations (in this case sparse PCA implementations) also only provide the loading vector.
To be brief with my question, is a loading matrix the same as a weight matrix (i.e. $W=P$?). If not, how do I obtain $W$? What is the difference?
